# Java regex for removing all characters except a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, email

I have a string including e-mail. There are probably extra characters before and / or after it.
input examples:

```
a1@b.com
a2@b.com abcd efg
x y z a3@b.com
p q a4@b.com x z
asd[x5@c.net]gh
```

I want to remove the extra characters.

Desired outputs:

```
a1@b.com
a2@b.com
a3@b.com
a4@b.com
x5@c.net
```

Valid characters are a-zA-Z0-9._
So there are probably invalid characters before and / or after e-mail.

I tried this code to identify whether it is a correct email or not (this assumes that it is separated from extra characters by space), but I can not replace to the desired string (using s.replaceAll()):

```
if (s.matches("(?i).*\\s[a-zA-Z_\\.]+@[a-zA-Z_\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z_\\.]+.*") ||
    fields[2].matches("(?i).*[a-zA-Z_\\.]+@[a-zA-Z_\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z_\\.]+\\s.*"))
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Don't use `matches` or `replaceAll`.  Instead, set up a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), use `find` (which will find a pattern anywhere in the string), and use `group(0)` to return the string it finds.  It will be much easier to tell it to return the matched string than to tell it to remove the unmatched characters.

Comment: Valid characters are `a-zA-Z0-9._` ... How does your regular expression match the `12345` in the email addresses in your desired output??

Comment: Valid characters are a-zA-Z0-9._ 
Edited.

Comment: You're probably best off using this regex: \S@\S  Your regex will miss a ton a valid email addresses. There are a lot of valid characters allowed in an email address.

Comment: My email address is `T41$+$UCK$@like.wtf`. That is a perfectly valid email address. Your regex will not allow it.

Comment: @tobii, Qix: My question was not about the validating the characters. Since I have defined a set of valid characters, I wanted to extract the email mentioned in the approach of Nemo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher

This code will do what you ask for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testList = {"a1@b.com", 
            "a2@b.com abcd efg", 
            "x y z a3@b.com", 
            "p q a4@b.com x z", 
            "asd[a5@b.coom]gh"};

    Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})");


    for(String test : testList){
        Matcher m = EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(test);
        while (m.find()) {
             System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your definition of valid characters, try:

```
^.*?([\w.]+@[\w.]+).*$
```

and replace with capturing group 1

Answer (score 0):

A validation of email addresses is not possible. It is only possible to validate an *email-adress-like-appearence* - and even this task is quite tricky, due to new tlds with more than 3 characters.

So, you better find "invalid" email-adresses (mail sending will fail), then missing a valid one.

Use

```
([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.]+\@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+|\[[0-9.]+\]))
```

to grab anything that could be an email address.

```
  ([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.]+\@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+|\[[0-9.]+\]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nE1FiUqF-1K54SCz)